# I can adduser and login through the Terminal but not through the GUI

Tags: login, password, gui

What should I do in this case?

I added the user through "adduser" command. The user has a Home-Folder, but when trying to login through the GUI, it always says "wrong password"! What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure you used `adduser` and not `useradd`? This usually happens using `useradd` and it's due to a precise reason.

Answer (score 0):

The `adduser` command sometimes does not correctly assign a password.  The other command to add users, `useradd`, does not prompt for a password.  In either case, **if the password set is not recognized, you have to provide a password separately via the `passwd` command as superuser to replace the password.**

From the terminal, run `sudo passwd username` where `username` is the new user you created.  Give them a password, then try and login.

Comment: Ummm..you meant `useradd` ?

Comment: @heemayl did you even read the OP's post?  They used `adduser`.  Both `adduser` and `useradd` are valid programs to add users with.  Neither handles the password.

Comment: I believe `adduser` asks for the password, its a wrapper around `useradd`..i don't know if you are referring to some other point..do clarify please..

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `sudo` before `passwd`?

Comment: @heemayl well, the 'adduser' wrapper is a very poor wrapper, most sysadmins prefer useradd as adduser likes to cause problems.  Either way, if the password is not being recognized, resetting the password (either by a sudoer or as root) should fix the login problem.

Comment: @muru irrelevant - if the password is still not recognized they have to reset it.  Since 10.04 it has the chance to not accept the password correctly - I have observed that on 16 separate cases.  Also edited accordingly.  But all of you seem to be missing the point of my answer in that they should reset the password manually.

Comment: @muru how about the bold formatting instead, then?

Comment: noone of the solutions works..
anyone has another idea for this problem?

Comment: @ZelelB check the logs for the system, perhaps it's not a password problem?

Comment: where can i find them?